# Configuring zabbix server on centos 9 stream

Tags: linux, centos, zabbix

i've been trying to install those packages required for installing zabbix on centos 9 stream but i came to a problem. I've been following this guide for installing zabbix on official webpage here:

https://www.zabbix.com/download?zabbix=6.2&os_distribution=centos&os_version=9&components=server_frontend_agent&db=mysql&ws=apache but i got stuck on this packages instalations:

**dnf install zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-web-mysql zabbix-apache-conf zabbix-sql-scripts zabbix-selinux-policy zabbix-agent**

My error is:  Problem: package zabbix-web-deps-6.2.4-release1.el9.noarch requires zabbix-web = 6.2.4-release1.el9, but none of the providers can be installed

- cannot install both zabbix-web-6.2.4-release1.el9.noarch and zabbix-web-1:6.0.8-1.el9.noarch
- package zabbix-apache-conf-6.2.4-release1.el9.noarch requires zabbix-web-deps = 6.2.4-release1.el9, but none of the providers can be installed
- package zabbix-web-mysql-1:6.0.8-1.el9.noarch requires zabbix-web = 1:6.0.8-1.el9, but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install the best candidate for the job

Only thing i did on my VM before i ran this command was disabling selinux and firewalld and dnf update.

Should i install mariadb or php server before i run this command? I am kinda new and still learning and i haven't been able to find any solution on my own. Thanks very much for help.

Comment: I think the problem is this line - cannot install both zabbix-web-6.2.4-release1.el9.noarch and zabbix-web-1:6.0.8-1.el9.noarch,    If zabbix-web-1:6.0.8-1.el9.noarch is already installed you should remove it then try install again.    Otherwise something is wrong with the packages being requested and you'll need to check with zabbix support.